# Google App Engine Setup On OSX with python2 and3 both installed

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, installation

Can someone help me with this issue? I am using Mac and have python 3 and python 2 on it. But when I try to run the project, there's always a exclamation mark next to my project. I change the  python path to "/usr/bin/python2.7" but the mark persisted. And the log file is like this:

```
Value 'hello.udacity' for application does not match expression '^(?:(?:[a-z\d\-]{1,100}\~)?(?:(?!\-)[a-z\d\-\.]{1,100}:)?(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,99}[a-z\d])$'
in "/Users/bill/code/Udacity/html/hello.udacity/app.yaml", line 1, column 14
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you that the application ID isn't valid; it has nothing to do with what Python versions you have installed.

For the application name part, only letters, digits and dashes are permitted, and the application name cannot start or end with a dash.

Your application name `hello.udacity` contains a dot, which does not fit in the regular expression.